# Adding relative file paths in yaml (ROS)

Tags: ros

This maybe something very basic but I haven't been able to get an answer anywhere else thus far. I want to use roslaunch to run map_server and rviz consecutively in order to visualize a map. Here is how my launch file looks like -

```
<launch>
<node name="mapServer" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" 
    args="/home/<user_name>/catkin_ws/src/mapwork/img/map.yaml"/>
<node name="visualizer" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"/>
</launch>
```

It works but I do not want to hard code the .yaml file location, I would prefer a way wherein I can use relative location of the yaml wrt the launch file. Any ideas on how I can do that?

(The location of the launch file is - /home//catkin_ws/src/mapwork/launch/map.launch )

Comment: Just as a comment as cassinjas answer is good: `roslaunch` runs everything in the directory `~/.ros`, independent of the location of the launch file. This means you cannot use relative paths (or if you do, they all would have to be relative to `~/.ros` which is kind of pointless).

Comment: Ok, I'll keep this in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your launch file I assume `mapwork` is a package. If that is the case, you can use the `find` package command as follows:

```
<launch>
  <node name="mapServer" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" 
    args="$(find mapwork)/img/map.yaml"/>
  <node name="visualizer" pkg="rviz" type="rviz"/>
</launch>
```

The `$(find mapwork)` part will return the path to the package after running `source setup.bash` in `/home/<user_name>/catkin_ws`.
This find command is similar to the ros python call `rospack find mapwork`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. "find mapwork" didn't work in the terminal when I tried but it seems to have worked in the launch file.

Comment: In a shell, you have to use `rospack find mapwork` instead as I described earlier.

Comment: Yes, I also used rospack find mapwork in the shell and it worked but it did not work in the yaml file, could you explain why that is the case?
Also, one minor irrelevant correction in your answer, typically setup.bash is in a "devel" folder in /home/<user_name>/catkin_ws.

Comment: If you are trying to execute these commands within the YAML file, this  won't work. YAML interpreter are libraries independent of ROS and YAML does not specify any scripting utilities. Launch files on the other hand are designed to execute a set of commands within `$()`.
What you can do though, is use `ros::package::getPath(package_name)` in C++, where `package_name` is `mapwork` read from the yaml file. This will give you the package path.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Ciao!

Comment: Close the question if your question has been answered!